# Why "How to Run the Flow" option is not available in Record-Triggered Flows?

Tags: visual-workflow

Does anybody know why the "How to Run the Flow" option is not available in Record-Triggered Flows? This flow should run in **System Context Without Sharing—Access All Data**. Currently we have to set Modify All permission to user's profile to make sure this flow runs.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Record triggered flows always run in system mode without sharing, so it is not configurable on the flow itself. The same applies to the Scheduled flow and Process Builder

Recommend reviewing [doc](https://salesforce-flowsome.com/flow-how-to-launch-your-flows-and-in-what-context/)

I will reach out to the Salesforce team that owns this feature to have this information added to our [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5) too  and will update this thread as I have more inputs.

**UPDATE:** The documentation has been updated to reflect `Record-triggered : System, without sharing`

Comment: The Salesforce documentation still makes no mention of Record-Triggered flows.

Comment: Apologies. This got lost. I'm checking now ....

Comment: @Swetha The [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5) still doesn't clarify record-triggered flows.  As Jason Kuzmak mentions in his answer, we are still getting Flow failures that indicate the flow is running in user context and not system context.

Comment: Running user and system context are two different things; flows (almost) always run as the User who started the flow (whether a screen flow or a triggered flow via a record edit by the user).  System context means that access checks on entities are not enforced; System context without sharing means that sharing rules are also not applied.

Comment: A documentation bug #W-10706115 has been filed internally to have the [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5) updated.

Comment: [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5) says **Record-triggered System, without sharing**

Comment: This is super frustrating.   Documentation still says "Record-triggered" flows run in "System context without sharing" even though that is clearly not correct.  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5

Answer (score 5):

At time of writing this, it doesn't seem like it's currently possible to run record-triggered flows in system mode. You can demonstrate this by creating a flow that updates another record the user does not have edit rights to. That user will receive an insufficient privileges error when triggering the flow. 
This is something I found out after recreating several of my Process Builder flows in Flow Designer. I'm assuming this is something they'll change before they do away with Process Builder.

Comment: For reference: [the documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5) has been updated to state that record-triggered flows run in system context.