# Is this warning a problem when i trigger subflow (running in system mode) from a record-triggered flow?

Tags: visual-workflow

I found this question and answer where it is said that record triggered flow run with the System Mode (no sharing) [Why "How to Run the Flow" option is not available in Record-Triggered Flows?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348359/why-how-to-run-the-flow-option-is-not-available-in-record-triggered-flows?newreg=a4174ee386dd441ea30352c3a847e4f8)

But when i execute a subflow that is set to run in System Mode (no sharing) from a record triggered flow i get the following warning:

> The master flow is set to run in Default Mode. The referenced flow is
> set to run in System Mode without Sharing.

Is the answer of that question still true and can i ignore this warning?

(I would have commented on that question but don't have the reputation for it...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Flow Metadata Documenation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_visual_workflow.htm) lists the various run modes (`runInMode`)

> The context that the flow runs in. Valid values are:
>
> - **DefaultMode** — How the flow is launched determines whether the flow runs in user context
>   or in system context. In the UI, this value appears as User or System
>   Context—Depends on How Flow is Launched.
> - **SystemModeWithSharing** — The
>   flow respects org-wide default settings, role hierarchies, sharing
>   rules, manual sharing, teams, and territories. But the flow doesn’t
>   respect object permissions, field-level access, or other permissions
>   of the running user. In the UI, this value appears as System Context
>   with Sharing—Enforces Record-Level Access.

The doc seems to be missing the latest addition which is `SystemModeWithoutSharing`.

However, going off the above and **your specific scenario - the warning can be ignored**. While it's technically true that the `runInMode` is mismatched, *how the flow is run* in default mode determines the context and, in your example (*record-triggered*), that would be System Mode (as the other answer notes) which matches your subflow's context.

For other situations, this warning may be useful if the flow is being run in a different manner which would cause the resolved contexts to mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know from experience it's still true and **you can ignore the warning**. I haven't found any documentation on the matter.

The warning you see is displayed to let you know under which context the flow is going to execute.

My guess is that it's displayed because **in apex you can restrict the context the code runs in, by checking the permissions of the current user**. This way you can make an inform decision as to whether to use apex instead of flow, if you need to take the user's permissions into account for your use case.