# Why can't I pass all record fields from a record triggered Flow into an autolaunched Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow

For some users, I am seeing an error message from a record triggered Flow that says:

> Because Get_Account is passed to an action, subflow, or Lightning component, store the values of all Account fields that the running user has access to.

And that implies to me that the field-level-security of the record triggered Flow is different to that in the auto launched Flow.

I think it has to do with the "How to run the flow" setting.  When you write an auto launched Flow, you can choose from:

- User or System Context—Depends on How Flow is Launched
- System Context with Sharing—Enforces Record-Level Access
- System Context Without Sharing—Access All Data

And it seems that the first one is the default.

That first option is supposed to be explained by [Which Context Do Flows Run In?](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_distribute_context.htm&type=5). But the documentation (as noted in [Why "How to Run the Flow" option is not available in Record-Triggered Flows?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348359/why-how-to-run-the-flow-option-is-not-available-in-record-triggered-flows)) is incomplete - it doesn't refer to record triggered Flows.

I understand that record triggered Flows run in System Context. Is there any documentation that says whether an auto launched Flow invoked from a record triggered Flow is run in System Context?

Should I explicitly set the context of the auto launched Flow to System Context? Obviously, I could just try it, but I'd like to understand what's going on and, if possible, see documentation of how this is supposed to work.